# Geometri and Affine Transformation

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram and point $P$ divides $AB$ by a ratio of 2: 1. $AC$ and $DP$ lines intersect at $Q$ and $BQ$ and $AD$ lines intersect at $R$. Suppose $t$ is an affine transformation that successively determines the point $A, D,$ and $C$ to points $(1,0), (0,0),$ and $(1,0)$. The shadows $P, Q$ and $R$ respectively by transformation $t$ are ....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To get response you need to show us your effort and where you stuck.

Comment: i'm stuck to count the potition of shadow P, Q and R

Comment: Are you sure that the image points are $(1,0)$, $(0,0)$, and $(1,0)$?